# OpsCenter 5.0.1 - xhrstream HTTP Get request cancelled - 0 of 0 agents connected

Tags: google-chrome, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

Connecting to OpsCenter 5.0.1 on OSX Yosemite on the latest Google Chrome 39.0.2171.99 (64-bit) results in these `tcp xhrstreams` requests being cancelled and i get a message stating `0 of 0 agents connected`

This means that i cannot see any of the metricsdetails of the cluster.

`http://<redacted>/tcp/50903bfb23e7404daa000d7f69374303/xhrstream?nocache=0.2149110094178468`

Using Chrome Dev Tools and taking the cURL version of the Get request, does work from the command line and gives this output

```
curl 'http://<redacted>/tcp/b61e257a7f834de8abb048af46f55749/xhrstream?nocache=0.15578373544849455' -H 'Referer: http://<redacted>/opscenter/index.html' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36' --compressed -u admin:c071618d1f8eac06a7b7
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            11,113,opt014,pingTimeout,3011,213,opt015,pingInterval,30%
```

So i've validated that OpsCenter is up and running and returning the desired results.

I've also tested using the latest safari and firefox on my machine as well as different wired / wifi and internet connections and i have the same issue.

Using a colleagues machine, on the same network and everything works fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried adding the cluster again to OpsC? Are the agents running in each of your nodes? `ps -ef|grep datastax-agent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue certain environments have with the persistent connection between the UI and opscenterd.  You should be able to workaround this by switching that connection to use long lived polling instead, by adding the following to opscenterd.conf and restarting opscenterd:

```
[labs]
orbited_longpoll = true
```

We are in the process of investigating using a different mechanism altogether in the future that is more compatible with different environments.